# Complex conjugate of a simple function

Tags: complex-analysis

If i take the complex number $e^{i(3+2i)}$, it's conjugate is $e^{i(-3+2i)}$.

However, the conjugate of the function f, defined as $f(x+iy)=e^{i(x+iy)}$, is, according to my book: $\overline{f(x+iy)}=e^{i(x-iy)}$.

I can't understand this difference ...

Answer (score 1):

I think the book meant that
$$f(\overline{x+iy})=f(x-iy)=e^{i(x-iy)}$$
but otherwise the book is in fact wrong as you say.

Comment: Are there functions for which $\overline{f(x+ij)}=f(\overline{x+ij})$ ?

Comment: Yes, the exponential function and logarithm functions both have such a property - $e^{\overline{z}}=\overline{e^z}$ and $\ln{(\overline{z})}=\overline{\ln{(z)}}$

Comment: Mhm and the sin and cos functions ? How can I understand why some functions have this property ?

Comment: @AleQuercia Note this occurs iff $\overline{f(\bar z)} = f(z)$, which if you consider the power series expansion of $f$ implies that, for each coefficient $a_k$ in the series, we must have $\bar a_k = a_k,$ i.e. each $a_k$ is real. Thus $f$ must take real values along the real line. It is easy to check this is both necessary and sufficient. Thus both the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions will have this property, as will all polynomials, etc.

Comment: @AleQuercia an obvious example where this breaks is $\sqrt{z}$ since such a function is not even single valued on the real line.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen is there a theorem about that? I would like to study the proof

Comment: @AleQuercia Not sure there is a name; these things are known as "Real entire functions" though. Searching that should bring up plenty of results. The idea is as follows: it is very easy to see that if $\overline{f(\bar z)} = f(z)$ then we must have $$\sum \overline{a_k}z^k = \overline{\sum a_k (\bar z)^k} = \overline{f(\bar z)} = f(z) = \sum a_k z^k$$ so we must have $\overline{a_k} = a_k$ so each $a_k$ is necessarily real.

Comment: @AleQuercia The other direction is essentially identical: Suppose $f$ is entire and *real* (meaning $f(z) \in \mathbb{R}$ for $z \in \mathbb R$, which is equivalent to each $a_k$ being real - can you see why?). Then we have $$\overline{f(\bar z)} = \overline{\sum a_k (\bar z)^k} = \sum \overline{a_k}z^k  = \sum a_kz^k = f(z)$$

Now, things might get a bit more interesting if you start considering meromorphic or multi-valued functions, and I would have to think a bit about what you would get. The meromorphic case will follow locally at least, but will in general differ globally....

Comment: @AleQuercia ... minimally we need an even amount of poles to ensure the symmetry condition is met, but I am not sure this would give a global result. Note the proof above only works in any region where a Taylor Expansion makes sense, i.e. a disk not containing poles. Something really scary could be if we have poles on the real line - this would fundamentally break the above proof. In order to generalize I would probably have to more carefully write out the above proof and see exactly which hypotheses are used when. This result should also hold for multifunctions if we keep track of branch cuts

Answer (score 0):

Well write it out:
\begin{align}
 \overline{ e^{i(x+iy)} } &= \overline{e^{ix-y}} = e^{-y}\overline{e^{ix}} = e^{-y}\overline{(\cos x+ i \sin x)} = e^{-y}(\cos x-i\sin x)\\
&= e^{-y}(\cos(-x) + i \sin (-x)) = e^{-y}e^{-ix} = e^{i(-x+iy)},
\end{align}
so the book likely has a typo.